# Dynamic Material Design Lite Selectable Data Table

Tags: javascript, html, material-design-lite

I'm using Material Design lite and the selectable data tables. I'm trying to place the table rows in using javascript after getting the information from firebase.

I'm wanting to use the selectable rows as shown in the documentation (https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#tables-section) but when I place the rows using javascript, I don't get the checkboxes in the body of the table.

My HTML

```
<div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp full-width login-activity-card">
    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable full-width">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Login Time</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Login Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My Javascript

```
$(".login-activity-card .mdl-data-table tbody").html(
    '<tr>'+
       '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">1:53 PM</td>'+
       '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Aug 05, 2017</td>'+
    '</tr>'
)
```

I get the checkbox in the header but not on the rows.

[image]

I've seen on the GitHub repository that this was deprecated in 2015, yet it's still in the documentation today? It gave direction to use the Wiki but I didn't find anything in there.

Is this just completely impossible or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/krvajal/pen/LjvamX) with your code working

Answer (score 1):

The library is made for static content only. If you add dynamic content, you have to make sure to call `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()`.

For more details check the [wiki](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/How-the-Component-Handler-works) entry related to the `componentHandler`